# vb.net How do I press a button with No ID

Tags: vb.net

http://ifunny.mobi/c/ARFTAKZQ1

I need to press the like button, but it has no ID.  Can someone help me?

Comment: Which button? How are you accessing the HTML code? What have you tried (post it, please)? The ID is just one property, there are many other ones you can rely on.

Comment: Im using a webbrowser

Comment: Post your code and show what are you doing to rely on the ID; such that we can advise you how to rely on a different property (like the Class, suggested by Vlad); in any case, it should be more or less straightforward.

Comment: @varocarbas
WebBrowser1.navigate("http://ifunny.mobi/c/ARFTAKZQ1")   

WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("vote like").InvokeMember("click")

Comment: This is a very poor implementation. Bear in mind that the WebBrowser class allows you to analyse all the HTML information without any problem. Perhaps you should do some research on how to build a browser by relying on the WebBrowser class before coming here to ask why it does not work under certain conditions. In any case, you have an answerer (Vlad L), perhaps you should ask him.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it by the class name

```
class="vote like"
```

check if element's attribute `class` value is "vote like"